# UI moves when I put a ref in a Box/div

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ref

I have the following code:

[image]

and it looks like this:

[image]

I need to add a div with a reference inside it:

[image]

And if I do so, all the UI moves up. See this picture:

[image]

I realized this happens only when I add the `ref` attribute to the div.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: what are you doing with topElement Ref ???

Comment: This is a really long list of items, when I switch them and I reload a new list, I want the list to scroll top and I use this div to force the main div to be scrolled up. Otherwise, the scroll remains where it was.

Comment: you can do that easily by using scrollTop property, find scrollable element and set scrollTop to 0, document.getElementById('#eampleScrollableDiv').scrollTop = 0

Comment: It did finally work! Thank you :)

Comment: that's good let me add this as answer so you can mark it correct and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that easily by using scrollTop property, find scrollable element and set scrollTop to 0, document.getElementById('#eampleScrollableDiv').scrollTop = 0